# How to locally extend Base operator in Julia (in module)

Tags: module, julia, overriding, radix

I don't know how to locally extend a Base operator and I couldn't find anything about that. 
I can obviously redefine it in the global scope (REPL or module) doing :

```
import Base.-

-(x, y::Nothing) = nothing
-(x::Nothing, y) = nothing
```

But I would like to have this to stay private in my module and not exported automatically to the global scope, in order not to pollute it, and still be able to use extensions in some functions in the module.
I tried `let ... end` blocks or even to redefine it inside my module's functions but it seems to prevent from importing Base properly. 
I would like something like :

```
module MyModule
export my_visible_function

function -(x, y::SomeType) 
# Base.- extension with x and ::SomeType
end

function my_visible_function()
# code using Base.- extension
end

end
```

Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own `-` function that shadows `Base.:-` within your module. This will work as long as `Base.:-` is not explicitly called before you define your `-` function in your module. (More on that below.)
Then you can define your `-` function in such a way that it falls back to `Base.:-` for most calls.

Here's an example:

```
module A
export foo

-(::Any, ::Nothing) = nothing
-(x, y) = Base.:-(x, y)
foo(x, y) = x - y

end
```

```
julia> using .A

julia> foo(1, 3)
-2

julia> foo(1, nothing)

julia> 1 - 3
-2

julia> 1 - nothing
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching -(::Int64, ::Nothing)
```

Here's an example that shows that it's ok to use `Base.:-` in a function definition before you define your own `-` function:

```
# This works.

module B
export foo, bar

bar(x, y) = Base.:-(x, y)

-(::Any, ::Nothing) = nothing
-(x, y) = Base.:-(x, y)

foo(x, y) = x - y

end
```

The only time this won't work is if you explicitly call `-` (from Base) before you define your own `-`. Here's an example of that:

```
julia> module C
       export foo
       
       1 - 3
       -(::Any, ::Nothing) = nothing
       -(x, y) = Base.:-(x, y)
       foo(x, y) = x - y
       
       end
ERROR: error in method definition: function Base.- must be explicitly imported to be extended
```